# The build restored NuGet packages. Build the project again to include these packages in the build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package-restore

Error:

> The build restored NuGet packages. Build the project again to include
> these packages in the build. For more information, see
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317568

I get this error while building code in Visual Studio 2017.
As a workaround I have to clean the code and build again. Then I don't see this error.
Every time O build this error comes back. I have to clean first and then build. Anyone having similar issue?[image]

Comment: Hi All, still i am getting this issue. Can anyone suggest

Comment: Are you using nuget references or nuget package.config in your project? Have you tried to run `Update-Package -reinstall` in the Package Manager Console? I would also recommend removing the references and inserting them again. Let me know what happened afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning the comment from @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp into an answer

Run this command in the Package Manager Console

> Update-Package -reinstall

Answer (score 3):

Try to update "Microsoft.Bcl.Build" nuget package. This was the solution for me.

Comment: Bless you - this fixed things for me. In my case I updated Microsoft.Bcl.Build from 1.0.14 to 1.0.21 and magically the failing projects of my solution FINALLY started building again. No idea why/how this happened (was a new laptop) but thank God I'm past this now! 